The consequence of a good letter of recommendation when things do not work out
In a recent conversation I had with a University Professor about letters of recommendation he explained that if he recommends me (or anyone) and things do not work out, his letters become completely worthless.
This strikes me as rather extreme, as he can (and should) only assess me based on what he has seen in his collaboration with me (assume that he has been my supervisor for Masters or PhD and I want to apply for a PhD or post-doc) and many things can happen in the next workplace with the next supervisor that this rather limited time of collaboration cannot predict.
To what extent is his statement true? He clearly had other sectors of society in mind as well, such as banks and finance, industry etc. when discussing this. To what extent would the next employer/supervisor be forgiving/understanding this?

Don't most applications not work out? I'm not in academia, but I assume there are usually many applicants for a position, and only one of them can get it. Why is there any stigma associated with being among the rest? Especially to the professor.

@Barmar I interpreted "things not working out" as OP getting the position but not doing well in it.

@user1149748 Now I get it. And the professor is worried that his future recommendations will not be believed, not that past letters become worthless.

I think this is hyperbole; it's meant to communicate the professor's high standards for recommendations and that they see offering a recommendation as putting their professional reputation on the line. It's likely not meant as a statement that conveys a true/literal thing about recommendation letters in academia.
Certainly one professor who receives a positive recommendation from another professor for a student that doesn't work out may be skeptical of future recommendations from that person, and it's possible that these things could become parts of conversation among colleagues, but otherwise there's no central database for listing recommenders of students who went on to fail and therefore cannot be trusted.

And of course the reason it doesn’t work out is important too. If the student has only ever worked alone and focussed on research under the recommending professor and the recommendation is based on this, and the ‘new’ professor then throws the student into a heavily group work–oriented and admin-heavy position and this doesn’t work out because the student turns out not to be good at team work and admin or due to a clash of personalities… well, that can hardly be held against the recommending professor who had no way of knowing this.

@JanusBahsJacquet in an ideal world professor B that worked with the student following the recommendation from professor A would look at it that way. But professors are humans and humans tend to find fault when they can in other places than themselves. And the recommendation letter might have not made it clear that the student is a loner not fit for teamwork etc. Chances are that in any case the trust level in recommendations from professor A is reduced at the very least on professor B's side and gossip might widen the circle beyond what is objectively reasonable.

Let me rephrase it a bit. If I give you a glowing letter of recommendation, extolling your many virtues, but knowing that you are, in fact, sort of average, or even mediocre, then, if you later fail, as you may, that will come back on me with colleagues who know of the history and my mis-statements.
That may be all the professor intends.
I once gave a glowing letter of recommendation to a student applying to a top research institution. He truly deserved it, but he failed miserably in the doctoral program. Luckily I knew a person there who asked me about it. What I didn't realize at the time I wrote the letter was that the student was dying of AIDS at the time. He had no symptoms when he was in my courses or when I wrote the letter, but it advanced rapidly after he graduated and started the new program.
But, had that later conversation not taken place, my own reputation for honest evaluation would be damaged.
The mirror image story is that I once went out on a limb for a student (Russian immigrant) that I thought was brilliant, but who didn't do all that well on the GRE. He was in danger of not being accepted at a top research university. I knew the dean there, who asked me about my letter and I assured him of the likelihood of success and why I had such confidence. That former student was accepted is now a full professor at another top university.
Reputation matters.
I always avoid saying such over the top things as "best student ever" or "top 5%" since my memory isn't perfect.
And, if I think that an honest letter wouldn't help the student, I suggest that they look elsewhere.

The story about your student is unclear. You wrote a strong letter because you believed the student was good, the student, however, was ill and did not perform at that time. Can you please unpack the timeline a bit, I think I know what you mean, but it sounds contradictory or confusing as written.

@CaptainEmacs, better now?

Yes, clear now, thank you.

I would say professor's statement is a bit extreme, as quoted, but it reflects reality to a certain extent: every time one writes a recommendation letter, one bets (a part) of his/her reputation (at least, in the respect of the ability to judge professional qualities of other people) on the performance of the recommended candidate. So, indeed, if one recommends a candidate at some point and the things obviously "do not work out" in the sense that the candidate fails to perform up to the expectations raised by the letter, the next letter will carry less weight and, conversely, if the expectations are exceeded, the weight will increase. I doubt very much that the corresponding reduction or amplification factors can ever reach $0$ and $\infty$, so the "completely worthless" part looks like a clear exaggeration to me. But those factors may be noticeable, indeed.
I look at my reputation just as at any other spendable resource I have (money, time,...), so when it runs low, I become frugal and try to replenish it, but when it runs high, I'm using it to push for things I want to happen, even if doing so costs me a bit in reputation points (like, say, submitting a paper to some journal nobody has ever heard of instead of some "prestigious" one just because I like it for some reason and want to support it). However quite many people want to pile it to the sky (don't ask me why), so the attitude you just met is not very uncommon.
There are several other possibilities of what such a statement might mean in some particular conversation, but you haven't provided enough information to discuss them in any meaningful way, so I'll stop here.
Just my 2 cents...

I'm not that familiar with academia world, so take what follows with a grain of salt, and more like an answer for recommendation letters in general and not only academia. There are already good answers but in my opinion they don't insist enough on one detail, hence this answer.
This strikes me as rather extreme, as he can (and should) only assess me based on what he has seen in his collaboration with me (assume that he has been my supervisor for Masters or PhD and I want to apply for a PhD or post-doc) and many things can happen in the next workplace with the next supervisor that this rather limited time of collaboration cannot predict.
There are often other, objective assessment of your performance as a scientist/student/employee. Past projects you worked on, grading reports, papers you published, ...
A recommendation letter, as objective and honest it can be, is usually an implicit compliment by its very existence. Because the person writing it considers you as worthy of their personal recommendation, and that other means (grading reports etc) are not enough. Often, the recommendation letter is written from one person to another specifically, and engages the trust the recipient may have for the sender.
Regarding this, if "things go wrong", and the recipient is dissatisfied with your performance, the trust the recipient has regarding the sender may be reduced. In addition, some academic or professional domains have a small population, and everyone knows everyone. So words that "X recommended a bad student/worker/researcher" may travel extremely fast.
